# SQL Join 2 tables together command

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

[image]

I have 2 tables as outlined above and I want to pass the current teams name into the Previous_Club column of the Player table. I have the logged in Team user's Team_ID set as a session variable so I am trying to query the Teams_Name using this and then passing it across to Player into the Previous_Club column. But it keeps erroring out. You can see the sql command below.

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Player SET Previous_Club = Team_Name FROM (SELECT Team_Name FROM TEAM WHERE Team_ID = @Team_ID)", con);
```

Comment: I'd rather say re-design your tables. Create another table with player, club, start/end dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one;

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Player SET Previous_Club = (SELECT Team_Name FROM TEAM WHERE Team_ID = @Team_ID)", con);
```

Answer (score 1):

Query Error..Try this one

```
UPDATE Player 
SET Previous_Club = (SELECT Team_Name FROM TEAM WHERE Team_ID = @Team_ID)
```